# Converting some hexadecimal string to a decimal integer

Tags: java, hex, type-conversion

I wrote some code to convert my hexadecimal display string to decimal integer. However, when input is something like *100a* or *625b* (something with a letter) I got an error like this:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " 100a"     at
> java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)     at
> java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)

How can I convert my string with letters to a decimal integer?

```
if(display.getText() != null)
{
    if(display.getText().contains("a") || display.getText().contains("b") ||
       display.getText().contains("c") || display.getText().contains("d") ||
       display.getText().contains("e") || display.getText().contains("f"))
    {
        temp1 = Integer.parseInt(display.getText(), 16);
        temp1 = (double) temp1;
    }
    else
    {
        temp1 = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(display.getText()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget that hex is case insensitive, so you should check for capital A-F as well.

Comment: It is dangerous to conclude that only numbers with hex digits "a" thru "f" are hexadecimal.  It is quite possible for a hexadecimal value to not contain any of these digits at all.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

It looks like there's an extra (leading) space character in your string (*" 100a"*).  You can use `trim()` to remove leading and trailing whitespaces:

```
temp1 = Integer.parseInt(display.getText().trim(), 16);
```

Or if you think the presence of a space means there's something else wrong, you'll have to look into it yourself, since we don't have the rest of your code.

Comment: Good catch!  Never would have seen that.

Answer (score 17):

```
public static int hex2decimal(String s) {
    String digits = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    s = s.toUpperCase();
    int val = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        int d = digits.indexOf(c);
        val = 16*val + d;
    }
    return val;
}
```

That's the most efficient and elegant solution [I have found on the Internet](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/31datatype/Hex2Decimal.java.html). Some of the other solutions provided here didn't always work for me.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I tried to passing it the String number `0a470c00025f424a`. Even I tried to return `long` instead of `int`

Comment: In the for loop, just loop through each char in s.toCharArray(). I checked, it's quicker.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Impossible to remember at this moment, have passed 7 years :) I suppose for some inputs did not get always the expected output.

Answer (score 4):

```
//package com.javatutorialhq.tutorial;

import java.util.Scanner;

/* Java code to convert hexadecimal to decimal */
public class HexToDecimal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.print("Hexadecimal Input: ");

        // Read the hexadecimal input from the console

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        String inputHex = s.nextLine();

        try {
            // Actual conversion of hexadecimal to decimal

            Integer outputDecimal = Integer.parseInt(inputHex, 16);

            System.out.println("Decimal Equivalent: " + outputDecimal);
        }

        catch(NumberFormatException ne) {

            // Printing a warning message if the input
            // is not a valid hexadecimal number

            System.out.println("Invalid Input");
        }

        finally {
            s.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

My way:

```
private static int hexToDec(String hex) {
    return Integer.parseInt(hex, 16);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A much simpler way is to use BigInteger, like so:

```
BigInteger("625b", 16)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void htod(String hexadecimal)
{
    int h = hexadecimal.length() - 1;
    int d = 0;
    int n = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i<hexadecimal.length(); i++)
    {
        char ch = hexadecimal.charAt(i);
        boolean flag = false;
        switch(ch)
        {
            case '1': n = 1; break;
            case '2': n = 2; break;
            case '3': n = 3; break;
            case '4': n = 4; break;
            case '5': n = 5; break;
            case '6': n = 6; break;
            case '7': n = 7; break;
            case '8': n = 8; break;
            case '9': n = 9; break;
            case 'A': n = 10; break;
            case 'B': n = 11; break;
            case 'C': n = 12; break;
            case 'D': n = 13; break;
            case 'E': n = 14; break;
            case 'F': n = 15; break;
            default : flag = true;
        }
        if(flag)
        {
            System.out.println("Wrong Entry"); 
            break;
        }
        d = (int)(n*(Math.pow(16,h))) + (int)d;
        h--;
    }
    System.out.println("The decimal form of hexadecimal number "+hexadecimal+" is " + d);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

```
public static int hex2decimal(String s) {
    int val = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        int num = (int) c;
        val = 256*val + num;
    }
    return val;
}
```

For example to convert 3E8 to 1000:

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
sb.append((char) 0x03);
sb.append((char) 0xE8);
int n = hex2decimal(sb.toString());
System.out.println(n); //will print 1000.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to get the digit:

```
public int digitToValue(char c) {
   (c >= '&' && c <= '9') return c - '0';
   else if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F') return 10 + c - 'A';
   else if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f') return 10 + c - 'a';
   return -1;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no brute-force approach which (done with it manualy). To know what exactly happened.

Given a hexadecimal number

> KₙKₙ₋₁Kₙ₋₂....K₂K₁K₀

The equivalent decimal value is:

> Kₙ * 16ₙ + Kₙ₋₁ * 16ₙ₋₁ + Kₙ₋₂ * 16ₙ₋₂ + .... + K₂ * 16₂ + K₁ * 16₁ + K₀ * 16₀

For example, the hex number `AB8C` is:

> 10 * 16₃ + 11 * 16₂ + 8 * 16₁ + 12 * 16₀ = 43916

**Implementation:**

```
 //convert hex to decimal number
private static int hexToDecimal(String hex) {
    int decimalValue = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < hex.length(); i++) {
        char hexChar = hex.charAt(i);
        decimalValue = decimalValue * 16 + hexCharToDecimal(hexChar);
    }
    return decimalValue;
}
private static int hexCharToDecimal(char character) {
    if (character >= 'A' && character <= 'F')
        return 10 + character - 'A';
    else //character is '0', '1',....,'9'
        return character - '0';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take advantage of ASCII value for each letter and take off 55, easy and fast:

```
int asciiOffset = 55;
char hex = Character.toUpperCase('A');  // Only A-F uppercase
int val = hex - asciiOffset;
System.out.println("hexadecimal:" + hex);
System.out.println("decimal:" + val);
```

Output:
hexadecimal:A
decimal:10

Comment: Please provide some explanation

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
public class Hex2Decimal {

    public static void hexDec(String num)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        int newnum = 0;
        String digit = num.toUpperCase();
        for(int i=0; i<digit.length(); i++)
        {
            char c = digit.charAt(digit.length()-i-1);

            if(c == 'A')
            {
                newnum = 10;
            }
            else if(c == 'B')
            {
                newnum = 11;
            }
            if(c == 'C')
            {
                newnum = 12;
            }
            if(c == 'D')
            {
                newnum = 13;
            }
            if(c == 'E')
            {
                newnum = 14;
            }
            if(c == 'F')
            {
                newnum = 15;
            }
            else
            {
                newnum = Character.getNumericValue(c);
            }
            sum = (int) (sum + newnum*Math.pow(16, i));
        }

        System.out.println(" HexaDecimal to Decimal conversion is" + sum);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        hexDec("9F");

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the value");
    String s = sc.next();
    //String s = "AD";
    String s1 = s.toUpperCase();
    int power = 0;
    double result = 0;      
    char[] c = s1.toCharArray();
    for (int i = c.length-1; i >=0  ; i--) {
        boolean a = true;
        switch(c[i]){
        case 'A': c[i] = 10; a = false; break;
        case 'B': c[i] = 11; a = false; break;
        case 'C': c[i] = 12; a = false; break;
        case 'D': c[i] = 13; a = false; break;
        case 'E': c[i] = 14; a = false; break;
        case 'F': c[i] = 15; a = false; break;  
        }
        if(a==true){
            result = result + (c[i]-48) * Math.pow(16, power++);
       }else {
           result = result + (c[i]) * Math.pow(16, power++);
       }

    }
    System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: I simplify the solution.

Answer (score -1):

This is a little library that should help you with hexadecimals in Java: https://github.com/PatrykSitko/HEX4J

It can convert from and to hexadecimals. It supports:

- `byte`
- `boolean`
- `char`
- `char[]`
- `String`
- `short`
- `int`
- `long`
- `float`
- `double` (signed and unsigned)

With it, you can convert your String to hexadecimal and the hexadecimal to a float/double.

Example:

```
String hexValue = HEX4J.Hexadecimal.from.String("Hello World");
double doubleValue = HEX4J.Hexadecimal.to.Double(hexValue);
```