# Convert android ID hex to decimal

Tags: java, android, hex

i get android id

```
GB.AndroidId=CheckDataNull(Settings.Secure.getString(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID));
```

result is a8606c9f06af341f = this is hex value 
i want to convert it to decimal value 
result must be **12132816826403861535** 
converted online with this site https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-decimal.html

i already tried this code

```
int decimal=Integer.parseInt(hex,16);
```

but get an error

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "a8606c9f06af341f"
```

then i tried
[Converting Hexadecimal String to Decimal Integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20110533/converting-hexadecimal-string-to-decimal-integer)
it's also don't work

this code works but output is different 
**input** = a8606c9f06af341f
**output** =859058534

```
public static int hex2decimal(String s) {
         String digits = "0123456789ABCDEF";
         s = s.toUpperCase();
         int val = 0;
         for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
             char c = s.charAt(i);
             int d = digits.indexOf(c);
             val = 16*val + d;
         }
         return val;
     }
```

**QUESTION : how can i get correct value ?** 
**input**=a8606c9f06af341f
 **output**=12132816826403861535

> **Correct Answer is**
>
> ```
> BigInteger decimal = new BigInteger(hex , 16);
> ```

Comment: An int has a maximum of 32 bits, or 8 hex digits. Use a long. `Long.parseLong`

Comment: You might also need `Long.parseUnsignedLong` in this case. See also [Java converting int to hex and back again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12005424/java-converting-int-to-hex-and-back-again)

Comment: @Nicolas thank you for link, Correct is  `BigInteger decimal = new BigInteger(hex , 16);` , but this `Long.parseUnsignedLong` gives wrong result

Comment: That depends on the maximum bit width of your ID. Long will support up to 64 bits, otherwise you have to use BigInteger like you found.